# How to programmatically create new file/folder in Drupal 7 files directory?

Tags: 7, files

I tried to create new file/folder programmatically inside Drupal's sites/default/files. But I'm getting this error: "Can't Open file".

Here is what I'm doing: When my registered user visits a certain page, I will be generating a new file and I will provide them with the download link. When I tried to create a new file I am getting "can't open file" message. I'm in localhost in MS Windows.

Are there any other writable folder other than sites/default/files for doing this stuff?

Below is my code:

```
$ourFileName = base_path()."/sites/default/files/members-pdf/testFile.txt";
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

Above code is written inside a views's template file.

I want to use PHP file API and not Drupal 7 file API.

Comment: The part `base_path()."/sites/default/files/members-pdf/testFile.txt"` doesn't seem right, because base_path() will at least return a single slash. Try if `base_path()."sites/default/files/members-pdf/testFile.txt"` works better.

Comment: Why do you want to use the PHP file API and not the Drupal file API? The latter is just a set of handy wrappers around the former.

Comment: For what it's worth: `$ourFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sites/default/files/members-pdf/testFile.txt';` should work fine assuming your web server can write to that folder, and your Drupal installation is in the web root (not in a sub-folder)

Comment: @marcvangend thanks it worked for me. I removed the slash and the base_path(). Just "sites/default/files/members-pdf/testfile.txt" worked for me.

Comment: @Clive thanks clive. i am about to use TCPDF for creating a pdf file which uses only php file api. And also your solution worked for me. In my case my drupal installation is in subdirectory so i have to add subdirectory name after $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].

Answer (score 8):

To create folders you can use [file_prepare_directory](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_prepare_directory/7) and pass FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY as second parameter like so:

```
$new_folder = 'public://newfolder/';
file_prepare_directory($new_folder, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```